# Is it possible to ignore object but have a boolean variable indicated what object exists in Jackson?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

I facing a problem parsing JSON object with Jackson.

My object looks like this:

```
{ ... { ... "element" : { ... "user" : {...} } } }
```

The object "element" has a nested object "user". I do not need to parse the actual "user" object, but I need to know what it has existed or not.

I have managed to do that with this code:

```
// just a dummy User object
@JsonRootName("user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class User {}

@JsonRootName("element")
public class Element {

...

    private boolean isUser;

    public void setUser(User user) {
        isUser = user != null;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to completely ignore User object and just set isUser variable to true if user object is not a null in the JSON via Jackson annotations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Annotate User property inside Element with `@JsonIgnore`, and setUser Method with `@JsonProperty`.. See if it's working..

Comment: No need, the private properties are ignored by default. My question is it possible to actually ignore User class completely and just check what object has been initialized in JSON without actually parsing it. User object is pretty big and there is many of them in the whole JSON, so I decided I can save alot of time, if this object will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Not just with declarations, although you can achieve it by something like:

```
public class Element {
  public boolean defined;

  public void setUser(Object bogus) {
    defined = (bogus != null);
  }
```

}

so that whatever JSON value matches `user` is bounds as "natural" type (Map, List), and then check is done.
If performance matters a lot, you could also write a very simple `JsonDeserializer` that checks current token (when invoked), calls `JsonParser.skipChildren()`, and return `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`, so you could have something like:

```
public class Element {
  @JsonProperty("user") // so deserializer called for 'user' property
  @JsonDeserialize(using=MyExistenceCheckingDeserializer.class)
  public boolean defined;
```

}

esp. if such existence checks are needed commonly.